# Plot shapefile city borders on top of cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, cartopy

I'm trying to plot the outline of Bay Area city/town borders on top of a cartopy terrain map using a shapefile obtained [here](https://earthworks.stanford.edu/catalog/stanford-vj593xs7263) and following [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187867/cartopy-plotting-shapefiles). For some reason, the borders don't show up, even when I specify borders are on top via  `zorder`. Am I missing something?

```
# import functions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

# Create a Stamen terrain background instance
stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=stamen_terrain.crs)

# Set range of map, stipulate zoom level
ax.set_extent([-122.7, -121.5, 37.15, 38.15], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 12, zorder = 0)

# Add city borders - not working
filename = r'./shapefile/ba_cities.shp' # from https://earthworks.stanford.edu/catalog/stanford-vj593xs7263
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(filename).geometries(), ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature, zorder = 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: No shapefile borders! Why?]

Comment: It doesn't look like the shape is even added correctly, meaning there is no geometry which intersects with the extent of the axes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it means to add the shape correctly? Not sure what change you're recommending.

Comment: I do not recommend anything; I just wanted to point out that the shape is not even drawn. So one would need to find the reason for that, not look into zorder.

Comment: I used [some files](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/) from naturalearth.com and with those the code runs fine. So potentially the file you are using is simply corrupted or is at least incompatible with cartopy.

Comment: Based on the metadata of the shapefile, the CRS code is EPSG:26910 or NAD83 / UTM zone 10N.  Using `ccrs.PlateCarree()` in ShapelyFeature() is not appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and @swatchai suggest, the CRS (coordinate reference system) parameter in [ShapelyFeature](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.14/matplotlib/feature_interface.html) `cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature()` was incorrect.

The proper EPSG (European Petroleum Survey Group?) code can be found in one of the .xml files included with the shapefile:

```
   <gco:CharacterString>26910</gco:CharacterString>
</code>
<codeSpace>
   <gco:CharacterString>EPSG</gco:CharacterString>
```

and passing this as the second parameter in `ShapelyFeature()` is all it takes to get the shapefile to plot the city borders properly:

```
# Add city borders
filename = r'./shapefile/ba_cities.shp'
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(filename).geometries(), ccrs.epsg(26910), 
                               linewidth = 1, facecolor = (1, 1, 1, 0), 
                               edgecolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1))
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)
plt.show()
```

[image: City borders now plotted]

Comment: I got this error `<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>`, no basemap was shown although the shapefile appeared correctly.