# Use ccrs.epsg() to plot zipcode perimeter shapefile with EPSG 4326 coordinate system

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, shapely, cartopy

I've obtained a shapefile of zipcode perimeters from [here](https://earthworks.stanford.edu/catalog/stanford-df986nv4623) and would like to plot them on top of a Cartopy map, as I did in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827373/plot-shapefile-city-borders-on-top-of-cartopy-map).

According to the source, this data is in EPSG 4326 coordinate system. When I attempt to plot the data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt 
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

# Create a Stamen terrain background instance
stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (mapsize,mapsize))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=stamen_terrain.crs)

# Set range of map, stipulate zoom level
ax.set_extent([-122.7, -121.5, 37.15, 38.15], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8, zorder = 0)

# Add city borders
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(shapefile).geometries(), ccrs.epsg(4326), 
                linewidth = 2, facecolor = (1, 1, 1, 0), 
                edgecolor = (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1))
ax.add_feature(shape_feature, zorder = 1)
```

I see the following error:

```
ValueError: EPSG code does not define a projection
```

Probably related -- when I look at the `ccrs.epsg()` function, it says that this EPSG code is not supported

```
help(ccrs.epsg)
Help on function epsg in module cartopy.crs:

epsg(code)
    Return the projection which corresponds to the given EPSG code.

    The EPSG code must correspond to a "projected coordinate system",
    so EPSG codes such as 4326 (WGS-84) which define a "geodetic coordinate
    system" will not work.

    Note
    ----
        The conversion is performed by querying https://epsg.io/ so a
        live internet connection is required.
```

Given this result, I also tried using `ccrs.Geodetic()`:

```
# Add city borders
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(shapefile).geometries(), ccrs.Geodetic(), 
                linewidth = 2, facecolor = (1, 1, 1, 0), 
                edgecolor = (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1))
ax.add_feature(shape_feature, zorder = 1)
```

But this also fails to show the zipcode perimeters, and shows this warning message:

```
UserWarning: Approximating coordinate system <cartopy._crs.Geodetic object at 0x1a2d2375c8> with the PlateCarree projection.
  'PlateCarree projection.'.format(crs))
```

I've tried `ccrs.PlateCarree()` too, but no luck. Please help!

Comment: From the content of `ZIPCODE.prj`, the projection is `NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N`. So it is not `EPSG 4326`. For detail, see https://epsg.io/26910 .

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried `ccrs.epsg(26910)` -- it does not return an error, but also does not plot the boundaries -- any thoughts on what to try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot data from different sources together, one must declare correct `coordinate reference system` for each data set. In the case of shapefile, you can find it in its accompanying `xxx.prj` file.

Here is the working code:

```
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt 
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shapefile_name= "./data/ZIPCODE.shp"
mapwidth, mapheight = 8, 8
pad = 0.25

stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
stm_crs = stamen_terrain.crs

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (mapwidth, mapheight))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=stm_crs)  #world mercator

# Set extent of map
ax.set_extent([-123.3-pad, -121.5+pad, 37.05-pad, 38.75+pad], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
# Plot base map
ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8, zorder=0)

# Add polygons from shapefile
# Note: the use of `ccrs.epsg(26910)`
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(shapefile_name).geometries(), ccrs.epsg(26910))

# You can choose one of the 2 possible methods to plot
# ... the geometries from shapefile
# Styling is done here.
method = 1
if method==1:
    # iteration is hidden
    ax.add_feature(shape_feature, facecolor='b', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.4, zorder = 15)
if method==2:
    # iterate and use `.add_geometries()`
    # more flexible to manipulate particular items
    for geom in shape_feature.geometries():
        ax.add_geometries([geom], crs=shape_feature.crs, facecolor='b', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.4)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: Your `method==2` example is quite helpful. With this, I was able to color polygons by value given in a separate dataframe:

`for counter, geom in enumerate(shape_feature.geometries()):`  
    `if data['Area'][counter] < 50:`  
        `if data['Population'][counter] > 500:`  
            `ax.add_geometries([geom], crs=shape_feature.crs,`  
                          `facecolor=color[counter], edgecolor='k', alpha=0.8)`  
   `else:`  
        `continue`  
`

Comment: @MichaelBoles :)